# Reactjs unable to print id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to ReactJS. I am trying to build an online shopping type of feature wherein we can increment the quantity and decrement it. Or directly remove an item using 'delete' button. I am trying to print the id of the button which is clicked, using console.log("delete clicked",counterId); in "counters.jsx". But some how it gives me undefined each time. Here is my code.

counters.jsx

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import Counter from './counter';

class Counters extends Component {
    state = {
        counters:[
            {id:1,value:4},
            {id:2,value:0},
            {id:3,value:3},
            {id:4,value:0}
        ]
    };

    handleDelete=(counterId)=>{
        console.log("delete clicked",counterId);
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.counters.map(counter=>
                    <Counter key={counter.id} onDelete={this.handleDelete} value={counter.value}/>)}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Counters;
```

counter.jsx

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';

class Counter extends Component{
    state={
        value: this.props.value 
    };

    handleIncrement=()=>{
        this.setState({value:this.state.value+1});
    }

    handleDecrement=()=>{       
        this.setState({value:this.state.value-1});
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <p>
                <span className={this.getBadgeClasses()}>{this.formatCount()}</span>
                <button onClick={this.handleIncrement} className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm m-1">Increment</button>
                <button onClick={this.handleDecrement} className="btn btn-warning btn-sm m-1">Decrement</button>
                <button onClick={()=>this.props.onDelete(this.props.id)} className="btn btn-danger btn-sm m-1">Delete</button>
                </p>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }

    getBadgeClasses(){
        let classes="badge m-2 badge-";
        classes+=this.state.value===0?"warning":"primary";
        return classes;
    }

    formatCount(){
        const {value} = this.state;
        return value===0 ? 'Zero': value;
    }
}

export default Counter;
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this once.
https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys-must-only-be-unique-among-siblings

With the example above, the Post component can read props.id, but not props.key.

Therefore, you have to add props.id={counter.id}!

counters.jsx
before

```
render(){
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.counters.map(counter=>
                <Counter key={counter.id} onDelete={this.handleDelete} value={counter.value}/>)}
        </div>
    );
}
```

after

```
render(){
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.counters.map((counter, index)=>
                <Counter key={index} id={counter.id} onDelete={this.handleDelete} value={counter.value}/>)}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer. But I am new to react, Can you please tell where exactly I need to do this modification?

Comment: Worked fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing `counter` as a prop to your `Counter` component, you are just passing `counter.value`. Instead of doing this pass the `counter` itself:

```
<Counter key={counter.id} onDelete={this.handleDelete} counter={counter} /> )}
```

Then in `Counter` component:

```
state={
      value: this.props.counter.value,
};
```

Also, if you separate your `handleDelete` function here and use its reference, it is not recreated in every render. Like:

```
handleDelete = () => this.props.onDelete( this.props.counter.id );
```

and

```
<button onClick={this.handleDelete} className="btn btn-danger btn-sm m-1">Delete</button>
```

But, your logic is somehow weird. You have a state in parent component, then you also keep another state in the child and do the increments, decrements there. Your parent's state does not change. Is that what you really want? So, you want multiple counters and keep their state separately like that?

Here is the full code:

```js
class Counters extends React.Component {
    state = {
      counters: [
        { id: 1, value: 4 },
        { id: 2, value: 0 },
        { id: 3, value: 3 },
        { id: 4, value: 0 },
      ],
    };

    handleDelete=( counterId ) => {
      console.log( "delete clicked", counterId );
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          {this.state.counters.map( counter =>
            <Counter key={counter.id} onDelete={this.handleDelete} counter={counter} /> )}
        </div>
      );
    }
}

class Counter extends React.Component {
    state={
      value: this.props.counter.value,
    };

    handleIncrement=() => {
      this.setState( { value: this.state.value + 1 } );
    }

    handleDecrement=() => {
      this.setState( { value: this.state.value - 1 } );
    }

    handleDelete = () => this.props.onDelete( this.props.counter.id );

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <p>
            <span className={this.getBadgeClasses()}>{this.formatCount()}</span>
            <button onClick={this.handleIncrement} className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm m-1">Increment</button>
            <button onClick={this.handleDecrement} className="btn btn-warning btn-sm m-1">Decrement</button>
            <button onClick={this.handleDelete} className="btn btn-danger btn-sm m-1">Delete</button>
          </p>
        </div>
      );
    }

    getBadgeClasses() {
      let classes = "badge m-2 badge-";
      classes += this.state.value === 0 ? "warning" : "primary";
      return classes;
    }

    formatCount() {
      const { value } = this.state;
      return value === 0 ? "Zero" : value;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Counters />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

In case of you want to see here is the alternative approach:

```js
class Counters extends React.Component {
    state = {
      counters: [
        { id: 1, value: 4 },
        { id: 2, value: 0 },
        { id: 3, value: 3 },
        { id: 4, value: 0 },
      ],
    };

    handleDelete = ( counter ) => {
      const newCounters = this.state.counters.filter( el => el.id !== counter.id );
      this.setState( { counters: newCounters } );
    }

    handleCounter = ( counter, direction ) => {
      const newCounters = this.state.counters.map( ( el ) => {
        if ( el.id !== counter.id ) { return el; }

        return direction === "up" ? { ...counter, value: counter.value + 1 }
          : { ...counter, value: counter.value - 1 };
      } );

      this.setState( { counters: newCounters } );
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          {this.state.counters.map( counter =>
            ( <Counter
              key={counter.id}
              onDelete={this.handleDelete}
              counter={counter}
              handleCounter={this.handleCounter}
            /> ) )}
        </div>
      );
    }
}

const Counter = ( props ) => {
  const { counter, handleCounter, onDelete } = props;

  function handleIncrement() {
    handleCounter( counter, "up" );
  }

  function handleDecrement() {
    handleCounter( counter );
  }

  function handleDelete() { onDelete( counter ); }

  function getBadgeClasses() {
    let classes = "badge m-2 badge-";
    classes += counter.value === 0 ? "warning" : "primary";
    return classes;
  }

  function formatCount() {
    const { value } = counter;
    return value === 0 ? "Zero" : value;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        <span className={getBadgeClasses()}>{formatCount()}</span>
        <button onClick={handleIncrement} className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm m-1">Increment</button>
        <button onClick={handleDecrement} className="btn btn-warning btn-sm m-1">Decrement</button>
        <button onClick={handleDelete} className="btn btn-danger btn-sm m-1">Delete</button>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Counters />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: yes i want multiple counters and keep their state separately.

Comment: Ok then, my answer works as its current situation. But generally, we try to write our components as pure as possible. You already have a state in the parent and you can use it to hold multiple counters without creating additional states in your child components. You child component will simply be a presentational one. Just a couple of buttons doing something.

Comment: @ChanGaikwad, in case of you want to see the alternative approach I've updated my answer.